# Найти "пересечение" двух массивов (т.е. новый массив), причём, чтобы его элементы были кратны минимуму из его кратностей в двух предыдущих массивов

Tags: c++, массивы

Дан массив x, содержащий k элементов, и y, содержащий n элементов. Найти их "пересечение" т.е. массив z, содержащий их общие элементы, причем кратность каждого элемента в массиве z равняется минимуму из его кратностей в массивах x и y.

У меня нет никаких идей, как это сделать. Как создать массивы - понятно, как найти их "пересечение" - теперь тоже понятно,но вот кратность я не могу понять.

```
int main()
{
    int k=0, n=0;
    int x[100], y[100];
    cout << "Enter the first array: \n";
    cin >> k;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number: \n";
        cin >> x[i];
    }
    cout << "Enter the second array: \n";
    cin >> n;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number: \n";
        cin >> y[j];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (x[i] == y[j])
        {
            flag = true;
            for (int l = 0; l < k; l++)
            {
                if (z[l] == x[i])
                {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                cout << "Common numbers: " << x[i] << '\n';
                z[k++] = x[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Можете использовать структуру map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приблизительно так:

```
map <int, unsigned> count;
vector <int> res;
for (int x : a) ++count[x];
for (int x : b) if (count[x]) --count[x], res.push_back(x);
```

Comment: не могли бы вы поточнее объяснить, как это сделать. Дело в том, что я не совсем понимаю работу функции map, хоть и прочитал пару статей о ней. Я создал 2 массива, размер которых нужно ввести, но вот как именно использовать эту функцию, не понимаю.

Comment: Кратность красиво решена

Answer (score 0):

```
std::sort(x, x + k);
std::sort(y, y + n);

int z[100];
int m = std::set_intersection(x, x + k, y, y + n, z) - z;
```